# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4

Tags: flutter

I have a code that enables users to fetch photos from the studio and then upload them to the MySQL database.The code works fine but there is only one problem. Uploading process in case the user chooses one image is successful. But if the user uploaded more than one image, the name would be repeated in the database with more than the number of images chosen to upload.It repeats the process and uploads more than the selected images to the database.

Example: I uploaded two pictures to the database and this is result:

[image]

This lines all just for two image.

I get this error with run code:

Full code

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),

  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: PickImages(),
    );
  }
}
class PickImages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PickImagesState createState() => _PickImagesState();
}

class _PickImagesState extends State<PickImages> {
  static final String uploadEndPoint = 'https://******************.php';
  List<Object> images = List<Object>();
  Future<File> _imageFile;
  bool _isVisible = false;
  String base64Image;
  List imagecode=[];
  List name=[];
  Future _onAddImageClick(int index, int type) async {
    if (images != null)
      setState(() {
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(
          source: type == 1 ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
          imageQuality: 50,
        );
        getFileImage(index);
      });
  }

  void getFileImage(int index) async {
    _imageFile.then((file) async {
      setState(() {
        ImageUploadModel imageUpload = new ImageUploadModel();
        imageUpload.imageFile = file;
        images.replaceRange(index, index + 1, [imageUpload]);
      });
    });
  }

  void showImageBox() {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = !_isVisible;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
    });
  }


  startUpload() async{
    String NameImage = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    {for(int i=0;i<imagecode.length;i++){
      await http.post(uploadEndPoint, body: {
        "image": imagecode[i],
        "NameImage": name[i],

      }).then((result) {
        if (result.statusCode == 200) {
          print('dddddddddddddddd ${result.statusCode}');
        } else {

        }
      });
    }}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Post Images'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: ListTile(
                trailing: Icon(Icons.attachment),
                title: Text('Attachments'),
                onTap: () {
                  showImageBox();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: _isVisible,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, right: 5.0),
              child: GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
                  if (images[index] is ImageUploadModel) {
                    ImageUploadModel uploadModel = images[index];
                    //base64 image
                    List<int> imageBytes = uploadModel.imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
                    // base64Image = base64Encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync());
                    base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes); //'base64Image' holds the base64 image string
                    imagecode.add(base64Image);
                    name.add(uploadModel.imageFile.path.split("/").last);
                    return Card(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.file(
                            uploadModel.imageFile,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            width: 300,
                            height: 300,
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 5,
                            top: 5,
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                size: 20,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  images.replaceRange(
                                      index, index + 1, ['Add Image']);
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Card(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return SafeArea(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: new Wrap(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new ListTile(
                                        leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                                        title: new Text('Camera'),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          _onAddImageClick(index, 1);
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      new ListTile(
                                          leading:
                                          new Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                                          title: new Text('Gallery'),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            _onAddImageClick(index, 2);
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          }),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('send'),
            onPressed: () {
              startUpload();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageUploadModel {
  File imageFile;

  ImageUploadModel({
    this.imageFile,
  });
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<=imagecode.length;i++

for(int i=0;i<imagecode.length;i++

Comment: @SpikeL Hi, I added an equal sign, but the problem was not solved

Comment: No, you have an extra equal in your startUpload method, removing it should fix your problem

Comment: @SpikeL  Sorry, I did not notice, I deleted it previously, but the code is still doing the process of saving more fields than the number of images in the database. I do not know what is the reason for that, but it seems that the code works more than one time in each click

Comment: @SpikeL Do you know the cause of this problem? Why is it saved more than once?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will change the subject so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Why did you repost it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479359/unhandled-exception-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-not-in-inclusive-range-0 Please do not delete questions as this leads to a question ban and creates a mess.

Comment: Hello brother, thank you / If I want to change the content, can I ask a new question? @Dharman

Comment: It's not a different question. It's the same content and the same title. Don't repost. Edit the old one instead.

Comment: No, I did not mean this question. I mean, now I want to ask a question differently @Dharman